# Trying to interact with a exiting browser window

Tags: vba

I am trying to work on a page thats already opened, I have managed to find and interact with the window, but I cant seem click on the  button the search button. See code below:

```
 Dim ele As Object
Set idoc = ie.Document
Dim eles As mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection
Set eles = idoc.getElementsByTagName("button")


Set objshell = CreateObject("shell.application")
intwincnt = objshell.Windows.Count
 
For inTWinNo = 0 To (intwincnt - 1)

strwintitle = objshell.Windows(inTWinNo).Document.Title
If strwintitle = "Articles" Then
Set ie = objshell.Windows(inTWinNo).Document
Exit For
End If
Next

 ie.getElementsByName("vin")(0).Value = "test"
 Set ele = ie.Document.getElementsById("vin-button")
 ele.Click
```

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="vin-utton"type="submit">DECODE</button>
```

Comment: "exiting" or "existing"?

Comment: Why is your code re-assigning to `ie`? Also, `shell.application` is for the desktop shell (i.e. `explorer.exe`), not for Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you for responding. However I got it to work re finding the browser window and populating the input, so because i got it to work thus far, I figured i was on the right path. Asit relates to why its assigning to IE, that's how i had gotten it to enter data in the IE browser.

Comment: For historical reasons shell.application returns explorer and internet explorer windows.

Comment: @user14797724 point noted. Is there another method you can suggest that will get it to work? As I said i got it working with the method I currently have, but I have no issues changing it a solution that's better suited.

Comment: There is a space missing before `type=` in the button.

Comment: @user14797724 that line with the space missing is not the code, that's the HTML from inspecting the button - thats not my code.

Comment: `getElementById` not `getElementsById`